# matching rows by datetime in DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to match the datetimes of two dataframes and would like to produce a smaller dataframe `prices_matched_df`, with columns `date` and `price` , with the following requirements:

Table 1 `revenue` (total 41 rows):
[image]

Table 2 `prices_df` (total 2651 rows):
[image]

I would like to match the column 'filing_date' in table `revenue` with the index (dates) in table `prices_df`. If the two dates are the same, add the `adjusted_close` value corresponding to the `filing_date` to the column `price` in `prices_matched_df`; if the two dates are not same, add the `adjusted_close` value corresponding to the nearest `filing_date` to the column `price` in `prices_matched_df`. For example, if the date 2013-03-31 does not have a corresponding value in column `adjusted_close` in table `prices_df`, find the nearest date, which is 2013-04-01, and add the `adjusted_close` value at that date to column `price` in table `prices_matched_df`. The output `prices_matched_df` should have 41 rows and 2 columns.

Here is my code, and it eventually does not append anything to the column `price`: I attach some explanations:

```
filing_dates = list(revenue["filing_date"])
# create a dataframe price_matched_df
prices_matched_df = pd.DataFrame({"date": filing_dates, "price": [0]*len(filing_dates)})
for i in prices_matched_df["date"]:
    for j in prices_df.index:
        if i == j:
            prices_matched_df["price"][i] = prices_df["adjusted_close"][j]
        else:
            idx = pd.to_datetime(prices_df.index).get_loc(dt, method="nearest") # find the index to the closest date if two dates does not match
            prices_matched_df["price"][i] = prices_df["adjusted_close"][idx]
prices_matched_df
```

**Updated:** I've also tried the left join method by `pd.merge`. It shows the values corresponding to the matched dates, so the values corresponding to the unmatched dates are missing values. I just want to impute the missing values with prices corresponding to the closest date from `filing_date`:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
prices_df_indexed = prices_df[prices_df.index.isin(filing_dates)].reset_index()
price_matched_df = revenue.merge(right=prices_df_indexed, left_on="filing_date", right_on="date", how="left").drop(columns=["date"])
```

I'm open to any solutions that can help me solve this problem. Thanks!

I have included what I tried above.

Comment: Pandas asof should suffice

Comment: @sammywemmy Hello, can you expand a little bit?

Comment: have a look at the docs for [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

Comment: If you provide usable constructors for a minimal example of the requirement rather than images then you are much more likely to have someone demonstrate a working approach.

Comment: @user19077881 Thank you! I'll update this in my next edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas `merge_asof` will help you probably.

[Tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

For Example:

```
prices_matched_df = pd.merge_asof(revenue, prices_df, left_on='filing_date', right_index=True, direction='nearest')
```

Comment: By modifying your argument, the syntax `prices_matched_df=pd.merge_asof(revenue, prices_df_2, left_on="filing_date", right_on="date", direction="nearest").drop(columns=["date"])` works.